# how to get a variable without going to next line

Tags: c++

Imagine we have two integers: `int a,b;`
And I want to get them by `cin>>` command, and my problem is that after `cin` command automatically goes to the new line and I dont want to.
I mean I want to get `int a` by `cin` command first and not go to the next line and then get the `int b` so I wrote :

```
int a,b;
cin>>a;
cout<<"\b\t";
cin>>b;
```

Whats Wrong? Whats the better way to do it?

[image]

Comment: You can't do this with `std::cin`. What you can do is `std::cin >> a >> b;`

Comment: Most implementations of `std::cin` will fetch and store data until an *end-of-line* character is received.  All characters are echoed back to the terminal after they are input.  So what you are seeing is the newline that was used to terminate `cin` is displayed, cause the cursor to advance a line (row).

Comment: @DimChtz have typed using namespace std; before it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you want with cin (or cin alone). C++ doesn't know that there's a terminal with a cursor (you could be typing on a line printer terminal with no ability to go back).

The standard response for when you need cursor control is to use ncurses (https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) or a package like that. If you have only one type of terminal (typically a VT-100/ANSI terminal) you can output a control sequence to move the cursor. See http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm for more details.